# How can I create a horizontal stacked bar chart with labels on the bars themselves as well as labels above the bars?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to create a horizontal stacked bar chart with labels on the bars themselves (currently using dataLabels) as well as labels just above the bars.
Here is a JSFiddle I've created that somewhat resembles what I am trying to accomplish. In this example I've placed the labels using `plotLine` labels, but I'm having a difficult time figuring out how to place the bars correctly in my real use case as I get the data for the bars through Ajax calls.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xwzfjbhe/3/)

I've experimented with `stackLabels`, `plotLine` labels as well as `plotBand` labels but to no avail. How can I place labels above the bars correctly every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use plotBands instead of plotLines - you can better control the alignment within the band, which can be set to cover the same portion of the graph as the bar itself.

An example.

Using your series data:

```
var series = [{
    name: 'John',
    data: [5]
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane',
    data: [2]
  }, {
    name: 'Joe',
    data: [3]
  }]
```

We can loop through and build a plotBands array from the same data:

```
var bands = [],
    prevData = 0;

$.each(series, function(i,ser) {
    var point = ser.data[0],
            name = ser.name;
    bands.push({
        from: prevData,
        to: (prevData + point),
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0)',
        label: {
            text: name,
            align: 'center'
        }
    });
    prevData = (prevData+point);
});
```

To make this match the order of the series as plotted, we need to set `reversedStacks: fals`e on the `yAxis`, as by default, Highcharts reverses the order of the series. Then we populate the `plotBands` with our generated array:

```
yAxis: {
  reversedStacks: false,
  plotBands: bands
}
```

In this way you can make use of the full feature set of the `plotBands` label properties.

Updated fiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xwzfjbhe/4/

And this adjusts to fit however many data points you have, provided you keep the same format (series.name, series.data[0]):

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/xwzfjbhe/5/

There are a number of other ways you can go about this as well, including:

- The `labels` property: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/labels
- The `renderer` function: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer